# Opening WSL remote window not working - command wslpath not found

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When trying to open a new Remote-WSL window I run into an error during the "Installing VS Code Server in WSL (details): Installing WSL components" step.  Appears it can not find the wslpath command.

I have tried looking at my PATH variables, I didn't see wslpath anywhere there nor do I know what the path should look like?  I also tried reinstalling my linux distribution but that did not help.

```
[2019-07-09 12:23:39.266] Launching C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe bash -c "'$(wslpath -u 'c:/Users/laida/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.38.8/scripts/wslServer.sh')' '0f3794b38477eea13fb47fbe15a42798e6129338' 'stable' '.vscode-server' 'C:/Users/laida/AppData/Local/Temp/vscode-remote-wsl/0f3794b38477eea13fb47fbe15a42798e6129338/vscode-server-linux-x64.tar.gz' 0  " in c:\Users\laida\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.38.8
[2019-07-09 12:23:39.562] /bin/bash: wslpath: command not found
[2019-07-09 12:23:39.562] bash: : command not found
[2019-07-09 12:25:10.024] VS Code Server for WSL failed to start. No messages received for 90s
```

Comment: Type this command `which wslpath`. If that does not return `/bin/wslpath` path then you are using old Windows 10 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this today when starting up Remote - WSL.  I am using an older Windows 10 version as @Biswapriyo noted, so I resolved it by installing wslpath from https://github.com/laurent22/wslpath
(Note: I also had to install php for that to work).
After that I was able to start Remote - WSL
I imagine that installing a newer Windows 10 version would probably work as well, but I'm unable to do that (managed image) and even if I were able that's kind of like killing an ant with a sledgehammer.